# HTML Canvas .fillStyle Not Rendering Color Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a game using the HTML canvas and am having some issues with the canvas' context .fillStyle method. This is my player variable and my drawPlayer() method:

```
var player = {
    x: width/2,
    y: height - 15,
    width: 7,
    height: 7,
    speed: 3,
    velY: 0,
    jumping: false,
    onGround: false,
    onLadder: false
};

function drawPlayer() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

As written, the cavnas renders the player as a yellow square. Yet, when I add a color component to the player and use .fillStyle with that player component (see below), the canvas renders it black.

```
var player = {
    x: width/2,
    y: height - 15,
    width: 7,
    height: 7,
    speed: 3,
    velY: 0,
    jumping: false,
    onGround: false,
    onLadder: false,
    color: "yellow"
};


function drawPlayer() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Comment: Well, it's rendering it yellow here. Anyway, try to change the fill color before add the player rectangle.

Comment: What do you mean it is rendering yellow here? I moved the ctx.fillStyle line up, and nothing changed. Can you elaborate a little more? Thank you.

Comment: Use the dev tools (hit f12) to break at `ctx.fillStyle = player.color` and find out what the value is. It could be you have modified it elsewhere. There is also a possibility that you have set some other context value that is causing the FX but you have not give all the code so we can not tell.

Comment: @Blindman67 is right. The question is not elaborated, though. If you want someone try to help you, show the full code.